# Template class object as an argument in a template class method

Tags: c++, oop, templates

I think the best way to explain what i want to accomplish will be through code:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct Foo {
   static void func(Bar<T> obj);
};              // ^ syntax error: identifier 'Bar'

template<typename T>
struct Bar {
   T data;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To resolve this, you just need what's called a "forward declaration":

```
template<typename T>
struct Bar;

template<typename T>
struct Foo {
   static void func(Bar<T> obj); //syntax error no more
};

template<typename T>
struct Bar {
   T data;
};
```

At the point where `Bar<T>` is referenced first the compiler does not have any idea what it is. You just need to add a declaration, beforehand, and the full definition of the template can still appear later.

Comment: I've tried it, but then i get some random errors from another .h file :/

Comment: We can only answer questions based on the information given in the question itself. This addresses the compilation error in the code that's shown in the question, which now compiles; and provides a brief explanation as to what the problem was. Nobody knows what's in "another .h file", and we cannot really answer questions referencing some other code that's not even shown. Feel free to post another question, providing more relevant information.

Comment: My bad, the other errors were actually my fault, it had something to do with a type used in the func() definition, w/e. So this answer actually solves it, thank you :)